# Why is JMeter losing a value?

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to load test a Moodle server. However my Regular Expression Extractor seems to lose the session key value.

Here is the Regular Expression Extractor I am using:
[image]

However, after sending roughly 15 HTTP requests, the variable reverts to its empty value. I have tried disabling the last call that successfully uses this variable, and the two following calls. But with no change.

I also tried creating a second instance of this extractor right before this variable goes null, and it still fails to work.

I am new to JMeter, so any additional information I should look up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you place regular expression extractor in your test plan?

Comment: Please post the complete hierarchy you've implemented in the Test Plan.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter PostProcessors are obeying [Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), to wit:

1. If you put the Regular Expression Extractor **as a child of the [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)** - it will be applied to that sampler only

   - Sampler 1

     - Regular Expression Extractor (applies to Sampler 1 only)
   - Sampler 2
2. If you put the Regular Expression Extractor **at the same level** as the Samplers - it will be applied **to all the samplers**.

   - Sampler 1
   - Regular Expression Extractor (applies to Sampler 1 and Sampler 2)
   - Sampler 2